# Could not open ssl 443 port server

Tags: linux, ssl, server, xampp, port

I have an external server that hosted in dreamcompute
Which it is can consider as virtual private server (vps)

I have test out using: https://ping.eu/port-chk/
the results:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 port is closed
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 port is open
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22 port is open
```

I have check my server port is open in linux:

```
username@server:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I'm able to access the web server internally by

```
http://localhost/
https://example.com/
http://example.com/
```

which all of them I set an index.php with a code:

```
<?=phpinfo()?>
```

From my experience, it was my router firewall problem, but I don't have the control to do it.
Maybe it was my dns or something else ?

Comment: It is your firewall. DNS cannot cause this.

Comment: @user207421 okay I try first, since I never access the router which owned by dreamhost :3

Comment: Make sure the service is actually running on the port.  In this case, probably check that your HTTP server is configured to run HTTPS.  Port will show closed if the service won't answer, even though the firewall isn't blocking it.

Comment: @TWBennet the server is running perfectly. I'm able to access https://example.com/ and http://example.com and http://localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps you need to do to check your port :
verify that you can connect from your local machine... you can just telnet to port 443, both on localhost (127.0.0.1) as well as on your machine's IP address.(You have already done this what I saw.) You should at least get an answer (ie. verification that there is a listener on that port).

Just for an example:

```
  $ telnet 127.0.0.1 443
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

This confirms port is listening

```
 $ telnet 127.0.0.1 443
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

We can also do by checking NETSTAT

```
  $ netstat -antl | grep 443
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52421         127.0.0.1:443           TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

For SSL we can use openSSL

```
    $ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
```

You may have to open and/or forward the address on your router or network firewall.

Hope it works fine!!
If not tell us, we will work on more solutions!

Comment: I had solved this problem by formatting my cloud server and yes it's working now. Thank you for the explaination :)